# Mapnik change xml config on the fly

Tags: mapnik, apache, tile-server, mod-tile

I have tile server running based on mapnik, mod_tile, and renderd. It was succesfully generate and serving tile using mapnik xml configuration which defined on renderd.conf. Something like this :

```
[default]
URI=/school_tiles/
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
XML=/home/brain/school/map.xml
HOST=localhost
TILESIZE=256
```

Now the scenario level up. I must renew the map based on data which queried by user. Example : if i hit http://xyz.com/?q=school&date=2014-01-01 then mapnik should regenerate map based on that query string and server response back with new tiles.

Is there any possibilities to change mapnik xml in renderd.conf on the fly ?, or what the best technique to solve this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks it possibles https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/dev/2013-October/027472.html